# Convert Earth-centered coordinates to rotating libration point (RLP) coordinates?

Tags: orbit, coordinate, lagrange-point, astropy

I'd like to plot the path of an object near L2 (like the Webb space telescope) in a rotating libration point coordinate system. That makes it is easy to distinguish halo orbits from more general Lissajous forms, etc. I expect to get Earth-centered coordinates from Horizons (see e.g. [nealmcb/jwst_orbit: Explore the orbit of the James Webb Space Telescope in Python](https://github.com/nealmcb/jwst_orbit)).

Here are details on the RLP coordinate system I'm looking for:: [Technical Notes - Rotating Libration Points](https://help.agi.com/stk/11.0.1/Content/gator/eq-rlp.htm)

Putting the origin at L2 as they suggesst seems good.

I was hoping to find an implementation in astropy, but it doesn't seem to be there.
Has anyone implemented it for astropy or another open-source framework?

Comment: That's essentially what I did in the corotating frame plots here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57832/38535

Comment: I did something like this [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58050/12102) but in a less-than-rigorous way, I rotated with the Earth/Moon barycenter's instantaneous position rather than at a steady rate.